# What is the origin of "summat"?

Tags: etymology, pronouns, scottish-english

In Scottish English, I know that the word *summat* is used in place of standard *something*. But what's the etymology of this pronoun?

It seems unlikely to me that *summat* could be merely a variant pronunciation of *something*. It also seems likely that the *sum-* part is from *some*, as with *something*, though I haven't a clue what the rest of it could be.

Comment: I didn't realize *summat* was Scottish English. I figured it was a severe contraction of *something like that*. I am interested to see if there is a good etymology out there, too.

Comment: I think it's more Northern English than Scottish. Glaswegian drunks excepted, the Scots tend to be more careful speakers than UK average, once you get past the strong accents. Probably Yorkshire (North-Eastern) "somewhat" becomes "summat", in the same way that Estuary (South-Eastern) English "something" becomes "summink".

Comment: +1 I was going to ask precisely this question myself. Didn't see it till today.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary says *summat* is actually a way to say *somewhat*. The word comes in the following forms:

> **Forms**:  α. ME sumhwat, sumwhet ( Orm. summwhatt), ME–15 sumwhat (ME sumwhate, sumwat(t, 15 sumwhatt); ME sumquat, ME sumqwat, 15 Sc. sumquhat; ME somȝwat, ME–15 somȝwhatt, ME–16 somȝwhat; ME somwat, ME–15 somwatt; ME– somewhat. **β. dial.17 sumet, 18 summat, summut, zum'ot, etc.**

So *summat* is a quicker, dialect-version of *somewhat* made by omitting the /w/ sound. The OED uses it in in various examples, like this:

> 1859    ‘G. Eliot’ Adam Bede I. i. viii. 172   It's summat-like to see such a man as that i' the desk of a Sunday!

Or this:

> Sense: Some (material or immaterial) thing of unspecified nature, amount, etc. Now arch. or dial.
>
> 1859    ‘G. Eliot’ Adam Bede I. i. i. 10   A man must learn summat beside Gospel to make them things.

I suspect that your meaning of *something* for *summat* came from this now archaic definition. *Somewhat*->*summat*, where *somewhat* had an original meaning along the lines of *something*.

Comment: As many people said, it is not Scottish, however, it is Yorkeshire English. If your answer is to be final I suggest adding that statement and further describing this fact as this is what the asker was interested in as well as aiding future viewers.

Answer (score 5):

I've always supposed it derived from *somewhat*.
While [UrbanDictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=summat) includes "Yorkshire slang for *something*" among its definitions of *summat*, the definitions derived from *somewhat* or from *something like that* seem more compelling.  Of *summat*'s etymology, [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/summat) says "Alteration of somewhat".  [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=somewhat) doesn't have an entry for *summat* but says *somewhat* derives from from *some* + *what*, ca. 1200 AD.

Answer (score 5):

It's the regular form for 'something' all over the northern part of the English world, including southern Scotland.  Very common to hear it in my Manchester (alongside owt and nowt).  It's thus neither 'Scottish' nor 'Yorkshire' but of a far wider area, more or less coterminous with the old Kingdom of Northumbria.

Ere's a bit out of an old translation of Aesop's fables, via OED:

> 1484   Caxton's. *Subtyl Historyes & Fables Esope* iii. xvi,
>   I deye for honger; gyue me **somwhat** to ete.
>   I die for hunger; give me **summat** to eat.

It serves the same purpose as 'something' but was constructed of other parts, i.e. from 'some' and 'what'.  It fell out of use as 'something' in the South, being retained only for the other usages involving the qualification of adjectives, adverbs and so on.

It's not from 'some' + 'aught' (i.e. 'owt' in my dialect), as that would literally translate as some-anything, which is a bit unnecessary.  And the au- ended up ow- in our area anyroad.

Answer (score 4):

It's Yorkshire for "something". Comes from the old English word "Aught", which is the opposite of naught: both are relatively archaic in BE. "Aught" means "something", "naught" means "nothing". Also see "owt" and "nowt".

Answer (score 2):

I am currently reading an English mystery novel by Margary Allingham set in 1927. It contains the following sentence:

> I've had several complaints lately of folk being scared to come along here in the evening, afraid they should be took for a rabbit or summat.

*(The White Cottage by Margary Allingham circa 1927)*

This seems to lean towards the definition of summat as 'something' instead of 'somewhat'. Of course, at this late date it's hard to know if this was a word in common use in 1927 or if she was using it for effect.

Answer (score 2):

I've read this expression in a book some years ago. It was explained that "summat" is a short form of "something like that", a "phrase" from Yorkshire. (I was in school and it was a text from our teacher so we made clear what it means.)

Answer (score 0):

I have always used and understood Summat/Sommet to mean; "something". As Nowt is; "nothing" and Owt is; "anything". More over, Innit is used in place of "isn't it". As far as I know, these particular slang terms are most common to Northern England, especially Yorkshire. Being native to the West Yorkshire region thee afore mentioned slang terms are very common there. I have not really heard them in the south of England that often. When I do, the speaker is without fail from the North. My ex-girl friend was born and raised just outside of London. Grew up with a very cockney accent. She has lived in the north now for over ten years. Her accent is odd to most folks up here because it is a mix of Northern and Cockney now, along with the fact she uses both Northern and Cockney slang in her speech. I always found her accent to be unique because of this. Others found it odd and confusing. lol. Well, there is my input. I do hope it was helpful.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U.  In general, it is preferred that answers cite sources to affirm their accuracy. [Here](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) is a link with some helpful information for answering questions.

Answer (score 0):

The Historical Thesaurus of English lists it as referring to an entity, being or thing, usually something. First usage around 1790. Hence perhaps its pervasive usage throughout the whole of the UK.

see here

http://historicalthesaurus.arts.gla.ac.uk/category-selection/?word=summat&label=&category=&startf=&endf=&startl=&endl=

Answer (score -2):

"Summat" is not restricted to Northern England. It's common in Reading, Berks, and in Oxford and---I suspect---over a large area of England, though I don't know where the cut-off points lie.

Comment: Please provide a link to a source in your answer.  For example, a dictionary entry, a blog post, or an etymological history.  This not only makes your answer stronger, it also helps other people who may have similar questions in the future.